# Interview: System/API design

Tags: system-design

This question was asked in one of the big software company. I have come up with a simple solution and I want to know what others feel about the solution.

> You are supposed to design an API and a backend for a system that can
>   allot phone numbers to people living in a city. The phone numbers will
>   start from 111-111-1111 and end at 999-999-9999. The API should enable
>   the clients (people in the city) to do the following:
>
> 1. When a client requests for a phone number, it allots one of the available numbers to them.
> 2. Some clients may want fancy numbers, so they can specifically ask for a number to be alloted to them. If the requested number is
>      available then the system allots it to them, otherwise the system
>      allots any available number.
>
> The system need not have to know which number is alloted to which
>   client. The same client may make successive requests and get multiple
>   phone numbers for himself, but the system is not bothered. At any
>   point of time, the system only knows which phone numbers are alloted
>   and which phone numbers are free.

The numbers from 111-111-1111 to 999-999-9999 roughly corresponds to 8 billion  numbers. Assuming that memory is not a constraint, I can think of the following two approaches (which are almost similar).

1. Maintain a huge boolean array of length 8 billion and have a `next` pointer that points to an array index (`next` is initialized to zero). If the value pointed by `next` is not free, then forward `next` until a free number is found. When fancy numbers are requested, just check whether the corresponding index position is free and return the number. The downside of this approach is, when allocating numbers in a regular way, if there is a huge chunk (say 1 billion) numbers in the middle that was allocated by fancy allocation, then the `next` pointer has to be moved 1 billion times.
2. To overcome the difficulty mentioned in the previos design, we can use some sort of a linked hashmap. We maintain a doubly linked list (this replaces the array in the previous design) and another array of the same length as the list where each element of the array points to a corresponding element in the list. So when allocating numbers in regular method, we advance a pointer in the linked list and mark nodes as and when we allocate (same as the previous method). When allocating fancy numbers, we can directly find the node in the list that corresponds to the special number requested by first indexing into the array and the following the pointer. Once the node is identified, short circuit the previous node and the next node so that we do not have to skip the used numbers one by one (which was the problem with the previous approach) when doing a regular allocation.

Let me know whether I am on the right track. Please enlighten me with any important details that I am missing.

Answer (score 11):

You can do significantly better in the anser to this question.

First you should design you API. The one recommended by Icarus3 is perfectly good:

```
string acquireNextAvailableNumber();
boolean acquireRequestedNumber(string special);
```

The second one returns true (and reserves the number) if it is available, otherwise returns false.

The question doesn't specify how you allocate phone numbers, so allocate them to suit yourself. Make the first 'next available' request return "111-111-1111", the next "111-111-1112" etc. This means you can record all the numbers allocated through 'next' by just remembering the last one allocated. (You'll need to ask whether '111-111-1119" is followed by "111-111-1120" or 111-111-1121", but that's the sort of thing you should be asking anyway. In any case, the important thing is you can work out what is the next number knowing the last allocated one.)

Special requests you will need to store individually. A hash table work, but so does a BST or simply an ordered list. It depends on what tradeoffs you want between space and speed, and how often special numbers are likely to be requested. I'll use a BST (ordered by the number) in the rest of this, for reasons I'll come to.

So, how do you code this? For the next allocated number:

1. Look at the last allocated number, and find the next in sequence.
2. Check that number hasn't been allocated as a special number. You can do this very quickly with a BST because if it's there, it will be the lowest entry in the BST.
3. If the number was in the 'special numbers' database, increment the 'allocated numbers' value (to include that number) and remove the entry from the special numbers. Then repeat this process until you get a number that isn't in the special numbers.

Note that this process ensures that all 'special numbers' lower than the last one allocated by 'next' do not appear in the special numbers database. As the 'last normal number allocated' increases, it absorbs any special numbers allocated that were less than that, removing them from the table. This is what ensures that when we ask whether the next number in sequence is in the special numbers database, we only have to look at the lowest entry.

Checking for a special number is easy. If it is lower than the last 'normal' number allocated it isn't available. Otherwise you check to see if it exists in the BST. If it doesn't, you add it to the BST.

You can optimize this process by storing not just single numbers in the BST, but storing ranges of numbers. If the allocated special numbers are dense, then it reduces the amount of space in the tree and the number of accesses to find if one is in there. During the test to find if the 'next' number discovers a rnage of size n, then you can immediately increment the highest normal number by n, instead of having to go round the loop n times.

Answer (score 1):

First, you did not prototype your APIs. For example, if I have to design these APIs I will publish 2 APIs.

```
string acquireNextAvailableNumber();
string acquireRequestedNumber(string special);
```

Second, you need to decide how you are going to implement it. code driven or data driven ?

You can maintain hash for all these numbers ( it will consume memory ) and quickly query the availability of the number. Or

you could maintain single list to store only distributed numbers ( less memory ). So, whenever request comes, you start searching 1 to n numbers in that list ( increased time-complexity ). if any first (or requested) number isn't there then you allocate it to client and add that entry in the list.

As, there are billion numbers, you will need to consider the trade-off between space and time.

You could also take the advantage of the database.

Answer (score 0):

To enhance previous answers, any BST may not be good enough as insertions or deletions can make it unbalanced. A balanced BST, e.g. Red-Black Tree, should be a good choice.
So, a Red-Black Tree can be created and filled in the beginning to represent available numbers, and each allocation should remove an element from it.

- `init(from, to)` - can be done in O(n) time, a straightforward implementation would be O(n log n). But that is a one-time initialization on your server's start
- `acquireNextAvailableNumber()` - should remove smallest element, time cost O(1)
- `acquireRequestedNumber(special)` - should make a search and remove element if found, guaranteed time cost O(log n)

In Java, a `TreeSet<String>` or `TreeSet<Integer>` could be used since it is implemented with Red-Black Tree.

The next question would probably have been that several request-processing threads would access your API, so since Java's TreeSet is not thread-safe, you should have wrapped it at initialization like so:

```
TreeSet numbers = init(...);
SortedSet availableNumbers = Collections.synchronizedSortedSet(numbers);
```